# Windows Get Rearranged When Monitor is turned off using an HDMI cable

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-radeon, displayport, usb-c

A common problem I have had for the longest time was that when I would use display port cables to connect my PC to a multi monitor setup, if I ever turned one of the monitors off, Windows would detect this as a display being disconnected, which would cause all kinds of problems; open programs getting rearranged, explorer (the desktop) hanging for several seconds, etc.). I've never had this problem using HDMI cables.

Historically, I have resolved this issue by using DisplayPort to HDMI cables between the graphics cards and the monitors, as this would prevent Windows from deciding the display was disconnected when a monitor was powered off. This has always worked for me, regardless of the monitor or graphics card.

I now am running an MSI x670 Pro WiFi motherboard which supports DisplayPort over USB-C using AMD integrated graphics. I have a USB-C to HDMI dongle attached to it, and then an HDMI to HDMI cable between the dongle and the monitor. Interestingly, with this setup, if I power off the monitor, Windows detects the display as being disconnected, despite the use of an HDMI cable (rather than a DP cable).

What's even more interesting, is that this ONLY happens with the USB-C port. There is also one HDMI and one DisplayPort port on the motherboard that use the AMD integrated graphics, and neither of these have this problem, assuming I use an HDMI to HDMI cable between the HDMI port and the monitor and I use a DisplayPort to HDMI cable between the DisplayPort port and the monitor. This ONLY happens over the USB-C port, which I wouldn't expect considering I am using an HDMI cable between the two.

Can anybody explain this behavior? What is inherently different about DisplayPort over USB-C that would cause this (particularly since it isn't happening with the motherboard's built-in DisplayPort)?